# Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project in java

Tags: java, eclipse

I have seen previous solution but my error is different then previous posts so please do not mark it duplicate question or something like that.

- I am getting this error when my eclipse is building work space.
- As i did nothing with my projects. Previously the same code was working fine.
- Till now i understand this is basically related to eclipse only.

Please tell me solution.

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse?

Comment: You say your error is different to previous posts - what *is* the error? Presumably you have more detail in the logs than *just* "Error running builder 'Java Builder'"

Comment: Information on where to find on-disk logs: https://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#Where_are_Eclipse.27s_log_files_located.3F

Comment: @Jon : thanks for reply i am getting a popup box with "Errors occurred during the build. Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project" this line. And the popup box coming again and again.error log have this two repeated error only 
1. Errors occurred during the build.
2.Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project

Comment: @sweerpotato: Yes i did restart my eclipse many time but its not work.

Comment: Do see the problem if you start a new workspace, with a new simple Java project? If so, it sounds like it would be worth reinstalling Eclipse. Please put the details into your question, rather than just as comments.